# Generating polymorph methods with wsimport for nillable's

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

When generating java client with wsimport for SOAP ws with an second, nillable (so called "optional") parameter, I got:

```
ISoap.mySoapMethod(Integer notOptional, Integer optional) { … }
```

instead of getting two methods:

```
ISoap.mySoapMethod(Integer notOptional) {
    return this.mySoapMethod(notOptional, NULL);
}

ISoap.mySoapMethod(Integer notOptional, Integer optional) { … }
```

Is there any way to archive this, or is there any reason why this is not a good idea?